# Uncaught TypeError in chrome while using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have written function:

```
jQuery.fn.alerting = function(obj) 
{
alert();
}; in script page
```

and called from 
jsp:

```
$("#obj1").alerting("#obj");
```

Its working fine in ie and firefox. but in chrome error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).alerting is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I got it while importing the Js file from Footer script it works fine. This error arise due to the invocation of statement before including js file.